# Unity physics collision issue, I think I need a pseudo kinematic rigidbody of sorts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I´ve got a pretty specific issue for which I´m not sure there is a fix. I want to have a rigidbody that behaves like a kinematic except when forces are added. Let me explain.

My context is I´ve got a ship in zero gravity, then some objects within that ship that do have gravity (Think of a gravity generator kind of scenario). The ship itself needs to be a rigidbody as well since it needs to be able to move with forces and such. But once I run this setup, the objects within the ship start pushing the ship down as soon as they touch the ship.

I know it technically makes sense but, is there no way to make it so that doesn´t happen? Like is there no way that the ship can be not affected by the objects within while still being able to be a rigidbody?

Hope this makes sense, thanks for any help!

Comment: Interesting situation, maybe [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/404420/rigidbody-constraints-in-local-space.html) could be relevant?

Comment: So it did help to get onto the correct track! I ended up using a second gameobject responsible for ship physics, then, the first ship, without physics so that nothing can push it, is translated to the "controller". It isn´t perfect by any means but it works for the initial prototype I am developing. Do want to say though that if a better solution exists, I would be happy to learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can increase the ship's mass on its Rigidbody component to decrease the amount that it can be pushed by other objects.

Comment: Increasing the mass was a solution I tried, and yes, it did decrease the amount it could be pushed, but not really enough. Issue was that at. First, it seemed fine, but slowly it would start moving, especially if multiple fairly heavier objects are added. I did find a temporary solution though, I have it written in the response above!